# Why is blender not using all of my ram?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, memory-management

[image: foo]

So I'm rendering this scene with blender cycles and I'm wondering why I get this

[image: bar]

when my computer has much more processing power.
Here's the computer I have: http://www.costco.com/.product.1128978.html  It has 16GB of ram, it should be able to do more than 181M right? If not, please explain to me why. Do I just need to get a better graphics card?

Comment: While 5 minutes isn't a long render time, I expect you are more concerned about the time to render than the amount of ram used. Have you enabled [gpu rendering](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/gpu_rendering.html)? You can also try the new [denoising option](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/settings/scene/render_layers/denoising.html) to get a cleaner render in less time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply because it doesn't need to use more.

My guess is that you assume that the rendering would be faster if used more memory. Sadly, it's untrue. And due to various bottleneck like memory latency, memory bandwidth (and probably more) : using more ram than it strictly need to use would probably slow down the rendering, not speed it up.

i have 32GB of RAM, my current rendering use ~32MB (which is ~1024  time than what it could use if it needed to).

EDIT : i'd like to add that RAM isn't "processing power", it's "storage"
 (temporary, and many order of magnitude faster than disk but storage nonetheless). In the same way, it won't go faster if you add more disk.